# How to rename the labels in ggcoef_model?

Tags: r, label, logistic-regression, r-forestplot, ggally

I'm trying to rename the coefficients of the variables in a graphic of a logistic regression in the `ggcoef_model` function. For example, in the variable "ID_GRADE" i want to rename "ID_GRADE[T.2]" as "2do grado". What can I do?

```
Call:
glm(formula = IMPL_RESP_NEG_2b ~ ID_GRADO + IMPL_TIEMPO.OBS_2 + 
    IMPL_EDUC_MODELA_2_cat, family = "binomial", data = BASE_IX)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2761  -1.1628   0.6914   0.8977   1.4785  

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  0.77867    0.63869   1.219 0.222780    
ID_GRADO[T.2]               -0.30623    0.33122  -0.925 0.355194    
ID_GRADO[T.3]               -1.12641    0.32051  -3.514 0.000441 ***
IMPL_TIEMPO.OBS_2            0.03769    0.01137   3.314 0.000920 ***
IMPL_EDUC_MODELA_2_cat[T.1] -1.09070    0.47608  -2.291 0.021963 *
```

This is the script in ggcoef_model:

```
ggcoef_model(LOGIMPL_NEC_GRUP_1aRegMultin.Mod,
             variable_labels = c(
               IMPL_TIEMPO.OBS_2 = "Tiempo de observación",
               IMPL_EDUC_MODELA_2_cat = "Modelado de las habilidades",
               ID_GRADO = "Grado escolar",
               IMPL_RESP_NEG_2b = "Presencia de respuestas negativas"),
             exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lc4O.png)